# Alloy changing comparison operators precedence for signatures

Tags: alloy

I have noticed Alloy's comparison operators precedence follows this order:

- comparison negation operators: ! and not;
- comparison operators: in, =, <, >, =<, =>.

A project I work in has defined two predicates **mySyn** and **Semantics** to evaluate Boolean expressions through these following signatures (**myNotEquals**, **myEquals** and **myGreaterThan**) built on Alloy's comparison operators, respectively (**!=**, **=** and **>**). Those are extending **BExp** abstract signature.

I would like to ask two questions (to simplify, I have omitted some pieces of code, by using **...** symbol):

1. Does the evaluation of those signatures follow the original Alloy order? I mean **myNotEquals** comes first, next **myEquals** and finally, **myGreaterThan**?
2. Is that possible to change the precedence of those signatures whose are going to be evaluated, for instance **myEquals** comes first, next **myGreaterThan** and finally, **myNotEquals**?

mySyn predicate:

```
pred mySyn[...] {
  ...
  , Semantics[evalC, evalB, evalA]
  ... 
}
```

Semantics predicate:

```
pred Semantics[ ...] {
     ...
     , evalB: BExp -> (State -> Bit)
     ...
}
```

Evaluating Boolean expressions

```
  all b: myEquals, s: State |  aritmethicExpr1[s] = aritmethicExpr2[s] implies evalB[b][s] = BitTrue else evalB[b][s] = BitFalse
  all b: myNotEquals, s: State |  aritmethicExpr1[s] != aritmethicExpr2[s] implies evalB[b][s] = BitTrue else evalB[b][s] = BitFalse
  all b: myGreaterThan, s: State |  aritmethicExpr1[s] > aritmethicExpr2[s] implies evalB[b][s] = BitTrue else evalB[b][s] = BitFalse
```

Thank you for your help :)